# How to update the Elasticsearch document with Python?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am using the code below to add data to Elasticsearch:

```py
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()
es.cluster.health()
records = [
    {'Name': 'Dr. Christopher DeSimone', 'Specialised and Location': 'Health'},
    {'Name': 'Dr. Tajwar Aamir (Aamir)', 'Specialised and Location': 'Health'},
    {'Name': 'Dr. Bernard M. Aaron', 'Specialised and Location': 'Health'}
]
es.indices.create(index='my-index_1', ignore=400)
    
for record in records:
    # es.indices.update(index="my-index_1", body=record)
    es.index(index="my-index_1", body=record)
    
    # Retrieve the data
    es.search(index='my-index_1')['hits']['hits']
```

But how do I update the document?

```py
records = [
    {'Name': 'Dr. Messi', 'Specialised and Location': 'Health'},
    {'Name': 'Dr. Christiano', 'Specialised and Location': 'Health'},
    {'Name': 'Dr. Bernard M. Aaron', 'Specialised and Location': 'Health'}
]
```

Here `Dr. Messi, Dr. Christiano` has to update the index and `Dr. Bernard M. Aaron` should not update as it is already present in the index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Elasticsearch, when data is indexed without providing a custom ID, then a new ID will be created by Elasticsearch for every document you index.

Hence, since you are not providing an ID, Elasticsearch generates it automatically.

But you also want to check if `Name` already exists. There are two approaches:

1. Index the data without passing an `_id` for every document. After this you will have to search using the `Name` field to see if the document exists.
2. Index the data with your own `_id` for each document. Then search with `_id`.

I'm going to demonstrate the second approach of creating our own IDs. Since you are searching on the `Name` field, I'll hash it using MD5 to generate the `_id`. (Any hash function could work.)

First Indexing Data:

```py
import hashlib
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()
es.cluster.health()
records = [
    {'Name': 'Dr. Christopher DeSimone', 'Specialised and Location': 'Health'},
    {'Name': 'Dr. Tajwar Aamir (Aamir)', 'Specialised and Location': 'Health'},
    {'Name': 'Dr. Bernard M. Aaron', 'Specialised and Location': 'Health'}
]

index_name="my-index_1"
es.indices.create(index=index_name, ignore=400)

for record in records:
    #es.indices.update(index="my-index_1", body=record)
    es.index(index=index_name, body=record,id=hashlib.md5(record['Name'].encode()).hexdigest())
```

Output:

```
[{'_index': 'my-index_1',
  '_type': '_doc',
  '_id': '1164c423bc4e2fcb75697c3031af9ef1',
  '_score': 1.0,
  '_source': {'Name': 'Dr. Christopher DeSimone',
   'Specialised and Location': 'Health'}},
 {'_index': 'my-index_1',
  '_type': '_doc',
  '_id': '672ae14197a135c39eab759be8b0597f',
  '_score': 1.0,
  '_source': {'Name': 'Dr. Tajwar Aamir (Aamir)',
   'Specialised and Location': 'Health'}},
 {'_index': 'my-index_1',
  '_type': '_doc',
  '_id': '85702447f9e9ea010054eaf0555ce79c',
  '_score': 1.0,
  '_source': {'Name': 'Dr. Bernard M. Aaron',
   'Specialised and Location': 'Health'}}]
```

Next Step: Indexing new data

```py
records = [
    {'Name': 'Dr. Messi', 'Specialised and Location': 'Health'},
    {'Name': 'Dr. Christiano', 'Specialised and Location': 'Health'},
    {'Name': 'Dr. Bernard M. Aaron', 'Specialised and Location': 'Health'}]

for record in records:
    try:
        es.get(index=index_name, id=hashlib.md5(record['Name'].encode()).hexdigest())
    except NotFoundError:
        print("Record Not found")
        es.index(index=index_name, body=record,id=hashlib.md5(record['Name'].encode()).hexdigest())
```

Output:

```
[{'_index': 'my-index_1',
  '_type': '_doc',
  '_id': '1164c423bc4e2fcb75697c3031af9ef1',
  '_score': 1.0,
  '_source': {'Name': 'Dr. Christopher DeSimone',
   'Specialised and Location': 'Health'}},
 {'_index': 'my-index_1',
  '_type': '_doc',
  '_id': '672ae14197a135c39eab759be8b0597f',
  '_score': 1.0,
  '_source': {'Name': 'Dr. Tajwar Aamir (Aamir)',
   'Specialised and Location': 'Health'}},
 {'_index': 'my-index_1',
  '_type': '_doc',
  '_id': '85702447f9e9ea010054eaf0555ce79c',
  '_score': 1.0,
  '_source': {'Name': 'Dr. Bernard M. Aaron',
   'Specialised and Location': 'Health'}},
 {'_index': 'my-index_1',
  '_type': '_doc',
  '_id': 'e2e0f463145568471097ff027b18b40d',
  '_score': 1.0,
  '_source': {'Name': 'Dr. Messi', 'Specialised and Location': 'Health'}},
 {'_index': 'my-index_1',
  '_type': '_doc',
  '_id': '23bb4f1a3a41efe7f4cab8a80d766708',
  '_score': 1.0,
  '_source': {'Name': 'Dr. Christiano', 'Specialised and Location': 'Health'}}]
```

As you can see `Dr. Bernard M. Aaron` record is not indexed as it's already present

Comment: I believe since the OP wants to also update existing documents, it would probably be more correct to just call index on all documents, regardless of if they exist in the index already. Elastic will automatically perform an update on a document if the ID already exists. Otherwise pretty much spot on.

Comment: The scenario provided by OP makes me take this approach. Else, as you said index all docs